# How to list classes/methods/lines, without being accessed after application running?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-coverage

I'am developing an API in C# with Visual Studio 2010 and ReSharper, which reads in and parses specific binary files and converts them into useable objects. Meanwhile there are tons of classes, methods, conditional constructs and so on.

Because I have no control over the file content *yet*, I don't know which parts of my project are really being executed.

**I want to know** if there's a *(free)* plugin for Visual Studio, which is able to create summaries like [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/userdoc/coverageview.html) for Eclipse does. Most important are places not being executed!

**Actually** I'm using a 30-day trial of [DotCover from Jetbrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/), which perfectly harmonizes with ReSharper and fits to my needs. Maybe you're familiar with other advisable plugins? ;-)

Comment: have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276829/code-coverage-for-c-net